# Google Sheets: How to display the result of a formula rather than the formula itself?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using formulas to fetch text from a sheet to another but the text is often too long to be read in the cell itself. The formula bar is no help either because it shows the formula itself, rather than the result.

Does anyone have any suggestions to work this out?

Thanks

Comment: what does the formula look like?

Comment: it's pretty much INDEX(MATCH()) to fetch some text from another sheet

Comment: if you use a vlookup() inside an arrayformula() you can pull for all cells at once using a single formula in just one cell. instead of one formula per cell.  you can also use { } array literal curly brackets to make it such that the formula itself is contained in a cell *outside* the range of cells in which you need the values to appear.  that way, you'll be able to see all the text in all the cells inside the formula bar, since there will be formulas when you click into the cell.  Difficult to demonstrate without a sample sheet to show you on.

Comment: Hmm that looks like it could work!

Would you mind trying to demonstrate it on this sample sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qhoxoYM4_iTjRv1v3w79oalVCURL0zE0jV4LbYiqx1I/edit#gid=1622857638

Basically I'm pulling the data from the "Source" sheet into the "Target" sheet. I'm matching column B on "Target" with column A on "Source".

Comment: I managed to use ArrayFormula with Vlookup and it does work! I didn't get that part about using the curly brackets so the formula is outside the range though....

Answer (score 0):

You could allow overflow, text wrapping, or increase the row/column size to the size needed.

Comment: I tried that, but sometimes the text is so huge it becomes very impractical...

Answer (score 0):

Try text wrapping in your menu. This will expand your cell.

[image]

Comment: The user is asking for a solution to see the result of the formula without changing the size of the cell.

Comment: The change of size will be done automatically. If you want content to flow to other cells, you can choose the leftmost icon.